# How to encrypt password with has_secure_password in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption, bcrypt-ruby

I've an API and I installed the next gem

```
 gem 'bcrypt'
```

And into my user model I specific that:

```
has_secure_password
```

My DataBase Have a field with name

```
password_digest
```

And when run the seeders Yea the password is encrypted, But when try to create a new user from my method the password is normal, This my method for create new user

```
def self.from_auth(data)
    User.where(email: data[:email]).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = data[:info][:email]
        user.name = data[:info][:name]
        user.provider = data[:info][:provider]
        user.uid = data[:info][:uid]
        user.password_digest = data[:info][:password]
    end
end
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not write the `password_digest` attribute directly. Use `password` (and probably `password_confirmation`) instead and Rails will do the magic for you.

Change

```
user.password_digest = data[:info][:password]
```

to

```
user.password              = data[:info][:password]
user.password_confirmation = data[:info][:password]
```

I advise to read the [docs for `has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 10):

The password is not being saved as a bcrypt hash.

From the bycrypt documentation

https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby

```
require 'bcrypt'

my_password = BCrypt::Password.create("my password")#=> "$2a$10$vI8aWBnW3fID.ZQ4/zo1G.q1lRps.9cGLcZEiGDMVr5yUP1KUOYTa"

my_password.version              #=> "2a"
my_password.cost                 #=> 10
my_password == "my password"     #=> true
my_password == "not my password" #=> false

my_password = BCrypt::Password.new("$2a$10$vI8aWBnW3fID.ZQ4/zo1G.q1lRps.9cGLcZEiGDMVr5yUP1KUOYTa")
my_password == "my password"     #=> true
my_password == "not my password" #=> false
```

So your code to store your user's password hash would look this

```
def self.from_auth(data)
  User.where(email: data[:email]).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = data[:info][:email]
    user.name = data[:info][:name]
    user.provider = data[:info][:provider]
    user.uid = data[:info][:uid]
    user.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(data[:info][:password])
  end
end
```

Then you can test it like the documentation says
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)